# Query to know if point is inside a polygon in Postgis 2.5

Tags: postgis

I have a polygon in the map defined as GeoJSON. Need to know if a point is inside that polygon.

Polygon:

```sql
ST_AsGeoJSON( 
 'POLYGON ((
    -69.62607888946572 -22.389720278609026, 
    -69.62632833490409 -22.39009971947581,
    -69.6252903200153 -22.3904196394022,
    -69.62501673469583 -22.390032759398007,
    -69.62553708324471 -22.389888919122058,
    -69.62607888946572 -22.389720278609026))')
```

Point:

```sql
ST_Point(-69.625137, -22.389777)
```

Need to know the correct way to ask Postgis this query.

We have tested different alternatives, some of them return the correct answer but don't know how they are different and which is the 'right way' (explanation of the difference between ST_Intersects, ST_Contains and `ST_DWithin` will be appreciated) . Do I need to "SetSRID" the point and polygon in the queries?

1: && operator, returns true, incorrect value

```sql
select
ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(ST_AsGeoJSON( 
 'POLYGON ((
    -69.62607888946572 -22.389720278609026, 
    -69.62632833490409 -22.39009971947581,
    -69.6252903200153 -22.3904196394022,
    -69.62501673469583 -22.390032759398007,
    -69.62553708324471 -22.389888919122058,
    -69.62607888946572 -22.389720278609026))')), 4326) &&
ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-69.625137, -22.389777), 4326)
```

2: ST_Intersects, returns false, CORRECT

```sql
select 
ST_Intersects(
ST_SetSRID(
 'POLYGON ((
    -69.62607888946572 -22.389720278609026, 
    -69.62632833490409 -22.39009971947581,
    -69.6252903200153 -22.3904196394022,
    -69.62501673469583 -22.390032759398007,
    -69.62553708324471 -22.389888919122058,
    -69.62607888946572 -22.389720278609026))':: geography, 4326),
 ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-69.625137, -22.389777):: geography, 4326))
```

3: ST_Contains, returns false, CORRECT

```sql
select 
ST_Contains(
ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(ST_AsGeoJSON( 
 'POLYGON ((
    -69.62607888946572 -22.389720278609026, 
    -69.62632833490409 -22.39009971947581,
    -69.6252903200153 -22.3904196394022,
    -69.62501673469583 -22.390032759398007,
    -69.62553708324471 -22.389888919122058,
    -69.62607888946572 -22.389720278609026))':: geography)), 4326),
ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-69.625137, -22.389777), 4326))
```

4:  ST_DWithin, returns false, CORRECT

```sql
select 
ST_DWithin( 
 'POLYGON ((
    -69.62607888946572 -22.389720278609026, 
    -69.62632833490409 -22.39009971947581,
    -69.6252903200153 -22.3904196394022,    
    -69.62501673469583 -22.390032759398007,
    -69.62553708324471 -22.389888919122058,
    -69.62607888946572 -22.389720278609026))':: geography,
 ST_Point(-69.625137, -22.389777):: geography,0)
```

In case you want to copy/paste in geojson.io:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -69.625137,
          -22.389777
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -69.62607888946572, 
              -22.389720278609026
            ],
            [
              -69.62632833490409,
              -22.39009971947581
            ],
            [
              -69.6252903200153,
              -22.3904196394022
            ],
            [
              -69.62501673469583,
              -22.390032759398007
            ],
            [
              -69.62553708324471,
              -22.389888919122058
            ],
            [
              -69.62607888946572,
              -22.389720278609026
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`&&`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html) is a bounding box intersection operator. It builds the squared box minX,maxX, minY,maxY around the polygon and will check if the point is within this square.

`st_intersects` is self explanatory.

`st_contains` is similar for a point in polygon operation (though a point on the polygon edge is not considered as being contained in the polygon). It is very different for line to polygon or polygon to polygon, as the 1st feature has to be entierly inside the other one (while for an intersection, if part of geom 1 is in geom2, the intersection is true).

`st_dwithin` checks if the minimum distance between the 2 geometries is less or equal the specified distance. With a value of 0, it is the same as `st_intersects`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand, in my case st_intersects and st_contains and st_dwithin are the same except if the point is in the very edge of the polygon. Would you then recommend using `st_intersect` then?. On the other hand... Should i use  `ST_SetSRID` and cast to `geography` for better results in the geoid an avoid incorrect answers due to spherical approximations?

Comment: @MarkoPerich the cast to `geography` is meaningful for large distances as great-circle arcs are used instead of straight lines. Using `St_intersects` is very common for this task